# Displaying Relations in Protege-OWL Editor

Tags: xml, semantic-web, owl, protege

[image: This image is the one I am getting after defining classes for ontology]I have created a basic Class hierarchy for my ontology in Protege-OWL Editor version 4.1. But I am not able to visualise Object Properties and relations between the classes in OwlViz other than the normal hierarchy or "is-a" relationship. So please tell me how to display "object properties" using OwlViz or OntoGraf ? or do I need to make some modifications in corresponding owl/xml file ?

Comment: consider asking at semanticoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, modifications will not help you. Object properties in OWL do not hold between classes but only between instances. For example, it is not possible to have a relation between *Government* and *Embassy* in (the decidable fragment of) OWL, but only between their instances. If *Government* has "USGovernment" as instance and *Embassy* "USEmbassyInEthiopia", you can assert that a relation (maybe **embassy-of**) holds between both.
Between classes, you can assert axioms. For example, you can state that all embassies must be an embassy-of some Government (Embassy SubClassOf: embassy-of some Government).
If you are interested in visualizing these relations, you may want to look at some graph-based ontology development tools such as [OBOEdit](http://oboedit.org/).

Comment: Hey, I came to know about "supermodel.jar" file in Plugins directory of Protege folder. This jar file can be found on this link http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~bauerj/supermodel/ . So what do you think to be more beneficial, the tool you suggested or the "supermodel.jar" file?

Comment: I think they will be quite different. If I understand correctly, Supermodel visualizes possible models (which are mathematical, set-theoretic structures over a universe so that they satisfy all the constraints laid out by the axioms in your ontology). OBOEdit would be an ontology development tool which (though with some restrictions) can produce OWL ontologies from graph-based representations. So I think you would prefer OBOEdit.

Answer (score 1):

[Top Braid Composer](http://www.topquadrant.com/products/TB_Composer.html) has full featured support for visualizing OWL Ontologies, schema and instances and SPARQL query results.  It is a commercial product, but there is a free edition that is pretty feature rich.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. Protege allows this. When you create relationships between classes and display in Ontograph the relationships descriptions aren't show but when you move the cursor over the line they appear. T